# Can't fill colour in tkinter arc in python.

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The Code:-

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
import random
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,height=700,width=700,bg='pink')
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,10,700,fill='blue')
canvas.create_rectangle(690,0,700,700,fill='blue')
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,700,10,fill='blue')
canvas.create_rectangle(0,690,700,700,fill='blue')
canvas.create_arc(110,9,130,29,extent=359,fill='black',style=ARC)
canvas.create_rectangle(290,500,410,510,fill='red')
root.mainloop()
```

Everything appears fine with color, only the arc doesn't get filled up.
How can I color the arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_arc.html), you cannot fill an arc except if its style is either `PIESLICE` or `CHORD`.

This actually makes sense: how would you fill a geometric object which is not closed?

You can simply remove the `style` attribute and it should work.

```
canvas.create_arc(110, 9, 130, 29, extent=359, fill='black')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Delgian. I should have gone through the documentation. And yeah it does make sense, we cannot fill color into unbound objects.

Comment: @Ritesh_BM By the way, maybe would you prefer to use [`create_oval()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_oval.html) if you intent to always set `extent=359`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use the `outline = colour` method while leaving the entry of `style = 'arc'` alone this will change the colour to what you want because of a tkinter querk that for small line widths you only ever see the outline. A more thorough way would be `outline = colour, fill = colour` this will be a complete uniform color no matter the thickness